# Medoo PHP db framework - Call to a member function fetchColumn()

Tags: php, mysql, database, frameworks

Using [Medoo](http://medoo.in/) PHP database framework and trying to count a number of rows with

```
$count = $db->count(
    'tournaments',
    [
        'is_season' => '0',
        'status' => '9'
    ]
);
echo $count;
```

Getting 'Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in medoo.php on line 816'.
Removing either of 'is_season' or 'status' will make the query count work.

What am I doing wrong? Or is the framework broken..?

Comment: We don't know. There's no call to `fetchColumn` anywhere in that code you're showing. If it's something deeply buried inside a library call, get in touch with the library owner. We can't debug 3rd party libraries here for you.

Comment: Your question refers to some lines which you didn`t provide

Comment: Sadikhasan came up with the answer. It appears I needed to add the 'AND' in my code. It works now.

Comment: I hate stackoverlow for such stupid users who close topic with no reason. Really helpful topic and helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this may work

```
$count = $db->count(
    'tournaments',
    [ "AND" => 
       ['is_season' => '0',
        'status' => '9'
       ]
    ]
);
echo $count;
```

Check [**Manual**](http://medoo.in/api/where)

Comment: Adding the 'AND' appears to work. Thanks!